# How to sort and get x oldest instances from Autoscaling Group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to develop an automation regarding instance draining and got stuck on how to get a list of a few oldest instances that belong to an ASG. The AWS API for Autoscaling group doesn't seem to have any timestamp for each instance. Not sure if anyone has been able to do this.

For now I'm thinking of using EC2 API to list instances with tag name, and sort it by date...

Comment: Query the ASG for the instance IDs and then query `describe-instances` to see their creation time

Comment: @jordanm that could work too...

Comment: If you're avoiding the extra call, yeah, you can use the tag but with a caveat: if you detach an ec2 instance from an ASG without terminating it, it keeps the tag but is no longer part of the ASG.